# Infinitive and present perfect together?

Tags: grammar, present-perfect, infinitives

I am not sure if the following sentence is correct

Nonetheless, I consider that **living with and have trained** my own dogs have helped me to gain hands-on experience

Can somebody please help me?

Thanks

Comment: No, it isn't OK. You need to say **living with and training** or **living with and having trained**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your phrase is that it mixes an infinitive verb form with the simple past, and the lack of sentence construction parallelism makes it difficult to read.

> **living with** and **have trained** my own dogs

There are many ways of rephrasing this, but you essentially want to make sure that both verbs use the same tense and take the same form. The corrected version that makes the least change is:

> **living with** and **having trained** my own dogs

---

As a note, you will also want to make another correction to your sentence:

> Nonetheless, I consider that living with and *having* trained my own dogs **has** helped me to gain hands-on experience.

Because of how you phrased the sentence, what you're discussing is a single idea that's a combination of the two things.

> I consider *that* **X** *has* helped me.
>   I consider *that* **living with and training my dogs** *has* helped me.

There is a way that you could use *have*, but the sentence would need to be changed slightly.

> I consider *that both* **X** and **Y** *have* help me.
>   I consider *that both* **living with** and **training my dogs** *have* helped me.

You need to decide if it's two things that have individually helped you, or a single collective thing.